# How do I read a text file from a website and load it in a UITableview

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview

My company dropped a bomb on me... I have to get the contents from a text file on a website like `http://mysite.com/file.txt`. The file contains about 500 lines with 3 fields on each line: `account number`, `last name` and `first name`.

I need to read these lines into an array and display in a `tableview` the `lastname` and `firstname` then upon selection from the `tableview` I need to send the account number to a variable that I can send back to another program. What do I need to put in my .h and .m files to make this work?

Comment: This is a pretty big question with several steps: 1. download file from website, 2. parse file into an array, 3. put the data from the array into a tableview, and 4. send the data to another program. What code do you have so far?

Comment: @David Brunow So true. But I will add one more point. To download the file, you must have web services acting on the web server. You cannot simply download the file using NSURLConnection by simply hitting the link.

Comment: @Evol Gate Could you use a WebView and then parse the textfile with javascript? I don't think I've tried that.

Comment: @David Brunow No you can't do that. At extreme that can give you the web page source but not the contents of the Text file. There is no way you can read text file contents like that, unless one knows How to Hack ;)